# Is it possible to have a several UIButton's open a single tableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitableview

I have a view controller with 6 buttons. I would like the buttons to open a tableViewController but each button would run a different query when clicked. Example Button1 would show a general list of places, Button2 would show editor's pick's, and so on.

Is it possible to have the 6 buttons point to one tableViewController and I recognize what button was pressed then run the associated query? Or should I have each button point to one tableViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this completely possible, but it's considered good practice. This method is much more efficient then creating 6 different table view controllers, especially if they will all have similar content.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Would it be better to use a push segue or modal segue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're loading your table data from an `NSArray`, make that array a public property in the `.h` file.

Now, your button press can perform the query and load an array, and you can get into the `prepareForSegue` method to pass the array you just loaded to the `TableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. You can use same tableviewcontroller for all 6 buttons..

You can have single instance of tableviewcontroller and whenever any of the 6 buttons clicked you can run the query and assign the result array to the tableviewcontroller and reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a generalized view, you should try to reuse. You could set value to a string based on your button click and pass the string to UITableViewController. Then query based on string value.